# Prove that the ideal generated by $x^3 + x + 1$ is not maximal in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is part of a larger homework problem. I am trying to prove that a quotient ring is not a field by showing that $\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ is not maximal in the ring of polynomials in the integers mod $3$. I've tried to factor it. I think I can work with the simpler condition that it is prime. I have zero experience with this situation. Apparently this same ideal is maximal in the polynomial ring of the integers mod $2$, but I can't yet prove that either. Any help is appreciated and that includes general advice about algebra.

Comment: A challenge here for me is working in Zsub3. Even factoring simple polynomials seems difficult in this new terrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The polynomial is not irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How does one recognize such a fact in general?

Comment: For degree $2$ or $3$, the polynomial is irreducible iff it has no root. Here we have the obvious root $x=1$, so $x-1$, or if you prefer $x+2$, is a factor. For higher degree polynomials, showing reducibility/irreducibility can take much more effort.

Comment: Is that all I need to show? Or must I factor this expression in order to show that the ideal is not prime? I'm working ahead on this problem, so I've been taught next to nothing so far and my book is somewhat obscure on this issue, focusing as it does on R[x] and Z[x]. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We don't have a field because we don't even have an integral domain. The polynomial factors as $(x+2)(x^2+x+2)$ so $[x+2][x^2+x+2]=[0]$. In terms of ideals, the ideal generated  by $x+2$ is strictly  bigger.

Comment: You don't need to factor *explicitly*, as I did above. It is enough to know that a factorization *exists*.

Answer (score 1):

A $3$ degree polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$  $\iff$ it has no roots in it.Check that $1$ is a root here

Comment: I see that, thanks. I'm trying to factor this expression.

Comment: How does irreducible imply non maximal? Does it factor into elements that are not in the generated ideal? Since the degrees of its factors are less than ?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3+x+1=(x+2)(x^2+x+2)\pmod3\implies$$

$$\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x+2\rangle\times\Bbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2+x+2\rangle$$

and you can check at once the direct product above isn't a field (not even an integer domain), as for example $\;\overline{(x+2)}\cdot\overline{(x^2+x+2)}=\overline0\;$ in the quotient ring, and none of these elements is zero there.